# How to join multiple csv files data in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

How to join multiple csv files dynamically in azure factory. I will have to join csv files dynamically in run time. Not sure number files to be joined.

Comment: could you please provide the source and sink type?

Comment: source and sink would be .csv. There will be multiple source csv files and I need to join then dynamically and store that joined result set in sink that is csv. It will iterate multiples times for multiple queries.

CSV1,CSV2,CSV3,CSV4 files will be in source, need to join CSV1xCSV3 output data will be store in CSV5, CSV2xCSV4 output data will be store in CSV6. This will be done dynamically

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: How about this: df= pd.merge(left, right, on="key")

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

New columns will be added to the right, and columns that match will be appended underneath matching columns.